# How to serialize and deserialize a C# array of integers?

Tags: c#, json

This should be really easy but I'm having some trouble so I thought it'd be great to get some help.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array is an array of Int32...

```
using (var stream = File.Create("file.xml")) {
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Int32[]));
    serializer.Serialize(stream, someArrayOfInt32);
}
```

Will create a simple XML file that is very easy to understand/modify. To deserialize it, use the Deserialize method.

In JSON format :

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Text;  
 /// <summary>
 /// JSON Serialization and Deserialization Assistant Class
 /// </summary>
 public class JsonHelper
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// JSON Serialization
     /// </summary>
     public static string JsonSerializer<T> (T t)
     {
         DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
         ser.WriteObject(ms, t);
         string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
         ms.Close();
         return jsonString;
     }  
     /// <summary>
     /// JSON Deserialization
     /// </summary>
     public static T JsonDeserialize<T> (string jsonString)
     {
         DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
         T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
         return obj;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to serialize them to. Do you want to save them as a *text file*? What about maybe a *raw binary file*? Maybe you want some *XML* or *JSON*?