# How to serialize/deserialze in json an object that contains int[]?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following class I want to serialize/deserialize with JSON.net:

```
class KeyStrokes{
    long[] timestamps;
    int[] keycodes;
    int[] updown;
}
```

Do you know if it is possible to serialize/deserialize objects of this class to JSON?  How about BSON?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Things you want to serialize should probably be public properties, not private fields. And Json.NET can easily serialize/deserialize data like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json Serialization in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278459/json-serialization-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know if it is possible to serialize/deserialize objects of this
>   class to JSON?

Yes, of course it's possible.

---

There are some threads with decent answers on SO, already:

[How to serialize and deserialize a C# array of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385161/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-c-sharp-array-of-integers)

[Json Serialization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278459/json-serialization-in-c-sharp)

---

Get JSON.NET: 
http://james.newtonking.com/json

Also, please make sure to invest more time before asking questions, else it your questions will be immediately put on hold.

Comment: Thank you.  It was straightforward.